# AppCode (or IntelliJ), update from TFS does override

Tags: objective-c, tfs, intellij-idea, appcode

We are using TFS for all our coding projects. Recently, it was decided to also put the Objective-C Projects into TFS. Yes yes....no comments on that decision please! ;-)
However, since there is no TFS integration in Xcode, and also not a good stand-alone TFS Client for Mac (as far as I know), we use JetBrains AppCodes TFS Plugin to put the Obj-C code into tfs. As long as only one developer works on the code, everything is ok. But as soon as a second one is working an the code we run into a huge show-stopper. If you update your local workspace via AppCodes TFS plugin, you OVERRIDE your local code instead of MERGING in new code.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there even a way to "update" your code in the sense of merging?

ANY help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It depends how you changed your local code. If it is checked out from TFS and changed, then it should be merged, if not I would guess it is an error in JetBrains interface. If you didn't check out the files and just changed it, than this is typical behaviour, because TFS doesn't know it was changed and therefore thinks it could overwrite it.

Comment: Hm, I've never tried with manual checkout. Visual Studio recognizes local changes and checks out these files automatically. I assumed that AppCode would do that too. I'll try that tomorrow. Thank's for the hint!

Comment: @MikeR: If you repost as an answer, I will accept it.